# writing a train_test_split function with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to write my own train test split function using numpy instead of using sklearn's train_test_split function. I am splitting the data into 70% training and 30% test. I am using the boston housing data set from sklearn.

This is the shape of the data:

```
housing_features.shape #(506,13) where 506 is sample size and it has 13 features.
```

This is my code:

```
city_data = datasets.load_boston()
housing_prices = city_data.target
housing_features = city_data.data

def shuffle_split_data(X, y):
    split = np.random.rand(X.shape[0]) < 0.7

    X_Train = X[split]
    y_Train = y[split]
    X_Test =  X[~split]
    y_Test = y[~split]

    print len(X_Train), len(y_Train), len(X_Test), len(y_Test)
    return X_Train, y_Train, X_Test, y_Test

try:
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = shuffle_split_data(housing_features, housing_prices)
    print "Successful"
except:
    print "Fail"
```

The print output i got is:

```
362 362 144 144
"Successful"
```

But i know it was not successful because i get a different numbers for the length when i run it again Versus just using SKlearn's train test function and always get 354 for the length of X_train.

```
#correct output
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(housing_features, housing_prices, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
print len(X_train) 
#354
```

What am i missing my my function?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're using `np.random.rand` which gives you random numbers and it'll be close to 70% for 0.7 limit for very big numbers. You could use [`np.percentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) for that to get value for 70% and then compare with that value as you did:

```
def shuffle_split_data(X, y):
    arr_rand = np.random.rand(X.shape[0])
    split = arr_rand < np.percentile(arr_rand, 70)

    X_train = X[split]
    y_train = y[split]
    X_test =  X[~split]
    y_test = y[~split]

    print len(X_Train), len(y_Train), len(X_Test), len(y_Test)
    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you could use `np.random.choice` to select indices with your desired amount. For your case:

```
np.random.choice(range(X.shape[0]), int(0.7*X.shape[0]))
```

Comment: on another note, should i be using random? because shouldn't the X_train correspond to y_train values? Or is that structure maintained even while using random?

Comment: @jxn You should use random because in original `train_test_split` you have `random_state` which means random output. Of course `X_train` corresponds to `y_train` because you're using the same mask for them.

Comment: @jxn alternatively you could use `np.random.choice`